# From determinant to polynomial equation

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

### Question

Hello,

I am solving following problem:

I have a determinant 3x3. It is full of numbers and there is one variable *x* in it. This determinant can be transferred to single polynomial equation. I can find roots of this equation then f.e. by [numpy.roots](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html). However the transfer from determinant to polynomial equation can be lenghty for sure.

So my question is:

Is there a simple way to make from determinant polynomial equation? (f.e. using sympy)

### Additional info

You can imagine the transfer as follows:

[image: 2]]

For bigger matrix 3x3 when each member can be polynomial of third or fourth degree, you can have like 200 polynomials coming out of the determinant which you have to sort and sum.

Comment: One usually does an eigenvalue analysis for matricies > 3.  Polynomials aren't used.  Use an algorithm like QR, Householder, Givens, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward in `sympy`:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
m = sympy.Matrix([[1 + x, 2], [x - 5, x**2 - 2*x + 3]])
print(m.det())
print(m.det().as_poly().coeffs())
```

Prints:

```
x**3 - x**2 - x + 13
[1, -1, -1, 13]
```